# Raspberry PI Touchscreen and KIvy App won't Quit

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy, touchscreen

I am using the Raspberry PI Touchscreen with Kivy. I am using the code I found on the internet from Matt Richardson
https://github.com/mrichardson23/rpi-kivy-screen

The code works correctly and the LEDs and buttons work - I was hoping to use it as a way of teaching myself Kivy as I need to write some code which needs 2 x buttons

However I can't get the kivy window to quit with any of the usual ways CTRL-C etc. Occasionally it does quite maybe 1 time in 10.

This means a reboot everytime I want to modify the code, which is pretty frustrating

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: Probably Esc should exit a kivy app, but I guess you tried that?

Comment: Can you share your code and I'll try it. I've got the same screen and use it for [my project](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=121392) and haven't had any noticeable issues.

Comment: Hey Martin, which touchscreen are you using? I have a PiTFT3.5 inch screen. I have not been able to get a kivy app to port to the screen rather than the HDMI. I have all but given up. Was wondering if you have the same screen and if so how you achieved this?

Comment: I am using the official 7" raspberry PI screen and the instructions to install KIVY were from here : https://github.com/mrichardson23/rpi-kivy-screen. It took over 2 hours to install, i had almost given up as I assumed it was going to fail so stick with it. The screen actually works very well but my lack of coding knowledge is probably letting me down. Ive tried Esc and all the usual ways of quitting an app. The code I am using is the example one from here https://github.com/mrichardson23/rpi-kivy-screen/blob/master/main.py  . All works great except that I can't exit

Comment: I have the same problem.  I'm running Jessie, not Wheezy.  Perhaps that's the cuase?

Answer (score 2):

My, this has been here a long time without an answer!
Here is what worked for me ro make CTRL/C exit:

```
import signal

def build(self):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
    return rootWidget

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)
```